# Rails validates...multiple :on options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Is it possible to have multiple entries for the `:on` option for the
`validates` validation?

Something like the following:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :presence => true, :on => [:create, :update, :some_other_action]

end
```

Basically I would like to run one particular validation when multiple
actions are called in the controller.  For example, I would like to
validate some user info on the `create` action, on a `update` action,
and possibly some other actions as well.

Although I don't want the validation to run on all the methods.

Also, if there is an easier way of doing this, that would be great too!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes for create and update!

:on - Specifies when this validation is active. Runs in all validation contexts by default (nil), other options are **:create** and **:update**

However think of these values as database data create or update statements, and not rails controller actions.  They may be doing similar things to data and the database, but they are different.
For example you may have another rails method that also updates the database, perhaps updating different fields, however the above ':update' will still account for that method even though it's not coming from a rails action with the name 'update'.

Comment: Actually you can use custom validation contexts. [:on - Specifies the context where this validation is active (`e.g. on: :create or on: :custom_validation_context)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates). You can then use `#valid?(:my_context)` or `#save(context: :my_context)`. Unfortunately there is no way to define multiple context's at once (neither with `on:` nor passing an array (or multiple parameters) to `#valid?`.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. Available in rails 4.1.

PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13754/files
Official doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate

Syntax: `on: [:create, :custom_validation_context]`

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Why? These `:on` events are NOT action names inside controller, but predefined ActiveRecord (MODEL) events, `:create` or `:update` or `:save`

There is no automatic connection between controller methods and model method.

Comment: This is no longer true and should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Had very similar issue, where I had to skip validation for certain controller actions, I tried the above ways but my problem was little different so they didn't work for me, so what I did is used attr_accessor and the unless configuration.

It will work for your cause smoothly.

in Model

```
validates :password, presence: true, unless: :skip_password_validation

attr_accessor :skip_password_validation
```

and when situation comes where I don't need the validation, I just make it true in controller

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.skip_password_validation = true
```